# Is it possible to get apk package name and version code in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get the package name of the apk in my react native code. I want to dynamically show the version code in my react native screen as I'm code pushing code from ms appcenter.

Comment: I'm currently using [this library](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) to get version number and few other details. I don't know if it include package name.

Comment: the package name is not included in that library

Comment: @AH. There is no out-of-the-box way. Using `getBundleId()` from `react-native-device-info` provides you with a package name, Milore is right. Be aware that the package name is `com.mycompany.app` on iOS and `com.mycompany` on Android (without the App name). @Milore would you like to add your comment as an answer, so it could be counted for you?

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf I wrote it as a comment cause I didn't check if the package name was included. Since you've confirmed my opinion and documented about it, it's more appropriate if it's you the one who provides an answer. I'll be glad to upvote it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all of these from [react-native-version-check](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check)